SVN: Have multiple externals in project
I have a SVN repository that contains modules (source and header files), in a structure like:

modules

module1

mod1.c
mod1.h


module2

mod2.c
mod2.h





Now I want to link these modules as externals into a project in another repository:

project

code

src

main.c
mod1.c (es external)
mod2.c (as external)


inc

foo.h
mod1.h (es external)
mod2.h (as external)







Best case would be a file-wise link like shown above. But I fail to find a way to do this using externals. Is it possible at all? Multiple questions about this have been asked but to the best of my search-capacities they are all quite old, so I thought I might raise this once more.
We use SVN in version 1.8
The reason to do this is the following:
The one repository contains generic libraries/modules that are developed and released within this repository. Each software project is done in its own repository but uses these modules/libraries. That's why I thought it would be the cleanest option to link to specific tags and use these as externals.
I know it's far from perfect, but for company-policy reasons I have to stick with SVN, and also with the structure of multiple repositories.

How would a mix of different repos and modules be "best case"? Regardless of whether it's possible, I'd keep the modules separated and adapt the include paths to find the source files.

one repository contains generic libraries, the other repositories are the actual projects which should use/include specific versions of those libraries. It's far from perfect, but that's what I have to work with. I will add more information/background to the original post

Just call svn propset svn:externals <parameters> and svn propget svn:externals to read them back. Do not forget to update your repo after changing properties.
You can write all externals into a file (per directory) and then call propset with the -F option. See svn help propset on details.
If you are using tortoise-svn, you can use drag&drop from the Windows Explorer (press shift and right-mouse key for this operation).
First caveat from personal experience: DO NOT cascade externals. E.g. Projekt a references a version of project b and this uses a module c. svn is completely broken here as of version 1.6 or 1.7.
Second caveat: Always use explicit versions, don't reference HEAD. Otherwise, you will never know how (which version of the external module) your project was built. And developers will always struggle with broken builds if someone changes the HEAD and others update.

My problem is to have multiple includes for the same folder. Image a "source" folder where i want to have all .c files.

Sure, just put an external for every item into the -F file on a line of its own. I'm using massively externals in one folder from different locations all over my repo

Yes, that is what I have now. It works, but it makes the directory messy, because the external only works on directories and not on files. But after alot of reading it appears that SVN cannot do what I have in mind, unfortunately

Externals do work on files and directories. I use it both

yes, but, for as far as I understand it, only on files of the same repository. That is the whole problem I have right now.
